Hibernate 6.6 fails if there is a generic @Id in a @MappedSuperclass
Having changed org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent from 3.3.4 to 3.4.0 (and implicitly Hibernate from 6.5.3.Final to 6.6.2.Final), I faced java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping for one of my inherited @Entitys.
The parent class.
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import java.io.Serializable;
// ... other imports

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Parent<K extends Serializable & Comparable<K>, C extends Parent<K, C>> {

    protected static final String LEADER_ID_COLUMN = "LEADER_ID";

    @Id
    @Column(name = LEADER_ID_COLUMN, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Nullable
    private K leaderId;

    // ... other fields

    @Nullable
    public K getLeaderId() {
        return leaderId;
    }

    public C setLeaderId(K entityId) {
        this.leaderId = entityId;
        return itself();
    }

    // ... getters/setters/equals/hashCode/toString

    protected abstract C itself();

}

One of the derived classes which leads to the exception. (I suppose that the rest inheritors have the same problem but the process doesn't reach them.)
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
// ... other imports

@Entity
public class Child extends Parent<Long, Child> {

    // ... fields/getters/setters

    @Override
    protected Child itself() {
        return this;
    }

    // ... equals/hashCode/toString

}

When my application reaches org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findAttributeMapping(String name) for leaderId inside Child entity, declaredAttributeMappings contains all the fields from both Parent and Child apart from leaderId. Plus superMappingType is null, so the result of the call is null.
    @Override
    public AttributeMapping findAttributeMapping(String name) {
        final AttributeMapping declaredAttribute = declaredAttributeMappings.get( name );
        if ( declaredAttribute != null ) {
            return declaredAttribute;
        }

        if ( superMappingType != null ) {
            return superMappingType.findAttributeMapping( name );
        }

        return null;
    }

That leads to the situation where org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.resolveEntityMember(Property property, EntityPersister declaringEntity) calls resolveVirtualIdentifierMember.
    private static Member resolveEntityMember(Property property, EntityPersister declaringEntity) {
        String propertyName = property.getName();
        AttributeMapping attributeMapping = declaringEntity.findAttributeMapping(propertyName);
        if (attributeMapping == null) {
            return resolveVirtualIdentifierMember(property, declaringEntity);
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }

resolveVirtualIdentifierMember( Property property, EntityPersister entityPersister) requries identifierMapping.getNature() to be VIRTUAL but in the case it's SIMPLE.
    private static Member resolveVirtualIdentifierMember( Property property, EntityPersister entityPersister) {
        final EntityIdentifierMapping identifierMapping = entityPersister.getIdentifierMapping();

        if ( identifierMapping.getNature() != EntityIdentifierMapping.Nature.VIRTUAL ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "expecting IdClass mapping" );
        }

        // ...
    }

The result is an exception.
ERROR SpringApplication Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:970)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(SpringExtension.java:352)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.resolveParameter(SpringExtension.java:338)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ParameterResolutionUtils.resolveParameter(ParameterResolutionUtils.java:136)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ParameterResolutionUtils.resolveParameters(ParameterResolutionUtils.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:59)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:311)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:287)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$before$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:204)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:203)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:153)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:144)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:100)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:144)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:100)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:63)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:400)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1849)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.resolveVirtualIdentifierMember(AttributeFactory.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.resolveEntityMember(AttributeFactory.java:765)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.resolveMappedSuperclassMember(AttributeFactory.java:781)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.lambda$static$2(AttributeFactory.java:746)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.buildAttribute(MetadataContext.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.processJpa(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:419)
    ... 79 more

I have tried Hibernate 6.6.3.Final. The behaviour is the same.
Any clarification is appreciated. Are there stricter requirements in the new version of Hibernate which I don't meet?

I have tried avoiding generics and made leaderId explicit (Long) in Parent. The problem persists.

I was facing same issue. What I did to solve it is, made @Id field part of children whenever it was part of @MappedSuperClass.
